# How to make wind effect

Tags: effects

I want to make a visible wind Blowing wind effect but i don't exactly know how to i have been messing with the setting for a while and so far smoke is the only one that seems to work.

Comment: Can you give an example of something that looks like what you want to achieve?

Comment: yes https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0v2z-GmU2zA 0:19